# how to select distinct records from my couchbase database?

Tags: couchbase

Let's say I have the following data in my database: 
http://pastebin.com/DTMG9SzY

I need to write a select statement that will return the LATEST record for each name, AND I need to return all the fields, not just name.

I have tried the following:

```
cbq> SELECT distinct(name) FROM `test-db` order by name, pb_date';
```

This returns the records / documents that I need, but I'm missing the other fields like pb_date etc.

**Attempt 2**

```
cbq> SELECT distinct(name), pb_date FROM `test-db` order by name, pb_date';
```

This just returns all three records, which is not what I want.

I'm poking around a bit more, but if someone could point me in the right direction, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this will helps you

```
 SELECT * FROM `test-db` GROUP BY name
```

if not let me know further

Comment: This just returns name. Also the query is incorrect. You can't do `*` while doing group by. It requires at least one field name mostly name. What can work is `select name from `test-db` group by name. But this is not what OP has asked.